# Remote SQL Server Connection works from SSMS but not from Application

Tags: networking, sql-server-2008, troubleshooting

We are troubleshooting a weird issue with our SQL Server 2008 server.  The application server runs a windows service that makes a DB connection via a connection string in its config file, and we end up with tons of the standard **'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.'** errors in the event log.

1. We have tried installing SSMS on the application server and connecting to the particular DB with those particular credentials works FINE.
2. Firewall is off on both sides.
3. TCP/IP protocol is enabled (and we use IP and custom port to force tcp).

We are stumped why it doesn't work via the app and need some pointers!

We have many SQL servers setup in our development and production environments and this particular setup doesnt appear to be any different.

**CONNECTION STRING:**

```
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Server=MYSERVERDB1; Database=MYDB; Network=DBMSSOCN; Address=192.168.20.161,2061; User Id=MYDBusr_vn;Password=blue123;Asynchronous Processing=True;Application Name=MYService;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Can you post connection strings?

Comment: Updated with connection string.

Comment: Can you also post the connection settings from SMSS?

Comment: Sure, where exactly do I find the SSMS connection settings to copy/paste?